# Why don't my bash shell scripts execute consistently?

Tags: bash, shell

I encountered some weird bahavior on my linux system. I created some bash script files, and changed their mode to be executable. However, some can be called and executed, while others can not (with err msg of command not found). As a result, I had cp a file based on the one which was able to be found and executed, then replaced the newly created file with the contents from a file which could not be executed as an ugly work around. It worked for me, but just want to know what caused this problem. It would be great if anyone know a quick fix since this problem is recurring.

For example, you can see the system is able to run blastem, but not bbrBlas

```
[c052308@sander ~]$ /home/c052308/bbrBlas -d ./BBR -l pt -p prior.txt -r
/home/c052308/bbrBlas: Command not found.
[c052308@sander ~]$ ./blastem

[c052308@sander ~]$ ./bbrBlas
./bbrBlas: Command not found.
[c052308@sander ~]$ ls -l bbrBlas blastem
-rwxr-xr-x 1 c052308 sashare 3108 Aug 18 17:03 bbrBlas
-rwxr-xr-x 1 c052308 sashare  798 Aug 12 12:06 blastem
```

Comment: Are they in different locations?

Comment: they sits in the same directory.

Comment: Could you provide an example?  Give a short example and tell us what your execution command is.  Also, sketch out the directory structure you're working in.

Comment: Do they all have the same she bang line
(i.e., #!/bin/bash
or something like it)

Comment: As a first step, I'd suggest doing `ls -l`on the suspicious files and post the result. There might be some notable differences in the permission.

Comment: For example, I found out that script 'hello' could be executed, while 'myloop' could not be found to execute, then I replaced the content of 'hello' (echo "hello,world") with the content from 'myloop' which loop through files in a specified directory for processing. And it worked for me. then I renamed the file hello back to myloop. That's my solution right now. 
I just don't understand the problem. You may think that 'myloop' was not executable, however, I double checked with ls -l and even reapply command chmod +x myloop several times to make sure. It did not work.

Comment: yes, it had the same line since I usually copy it from file to file

Comment: that's what I did and I could not find out any difference between files.

Comment: Please post the result, as suggested by nicolas78. Perhaps it's some tiny difference that you have accidentally missed.

Comment: @Jim:  Now, what's the directory structure?  Were the "hello" and "myloop" scripts in different directories?  You've been asked twice for some such information.  Again, show us some short examples, sketch out the directory structure, and tell us what your execution command was.

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x 1 c052308 sashare      594 Aug 16 17:02 newinput
-rwxr-xr-x 1 c052308 sashare       22 Aug 16 16:34 callnipt
where newinput is executible and callnipt is not

Comment: They are in the same dir, hello just echoes Hello world, and some details for myloop (actually called newinput:

[c052308@sander ~/BBR]$ pwd
/home/c052308/BBR

Comment: [c052308@sander ~/BBR]$ more newinput
#!/bin/sh
#clear preexisting reference file
if [ -e ./drugrec* ]
then
   rm ./drugrec*
fi
for (( i = 1; i <= 26; i++ ))      
do
echo "calling sas with -log ./sasout/createInput${i}.log -print ./sasout/createInput${i}.lst -sysparm ba
sedir=.,level=pt,searchIDnm=SOCseq,searchIdval=$i"
sas CreateBBRInput.sas  -sysparm basedir=.,level=pt,searchIDnm=SOCseq,searchIdval=$i -log ./sasout/creat
eInput${i}.log -print ./sasout/createInput${i}.lst &
done

Comment: It would be much more readable if you post output from `ls` and contents of shell scripts as edits to your original question (and use the code formatting button) so they are readable since comments don't support much formatting. What is the output of `ls -lb` on these files?

Comment: This is not an answer.  This type of post should go into the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your shebang line (i.e. first line, starts with `#!`) does not contain `\r` (`0x0d`) which may happen if you edited your script under DOS or Windows. Actually, make sure that your script does not contain any weird characters -- use `hexdump -C` to find them.